# INVALID_REQUEST_BODY in EnvelopeRecipients::update

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

Im getting the envelopes recipients using the GET `envelopes/{envelope_id}/recipients` endpoint.

After that i add the field `clientUserId` and try to update the envelope, using the POST envelopes/{envelope_id}/recipients' endpoint with the very same array that i got from return from GET method as body.

But is returned the following error:

"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'API_REST.Models.v2.recipientIdentityVerification' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path 'signers[0].identityVerification', line 1, position 120."

Obs: This was working last time i tested (december/2018)

**UPDATE:**

I enabled the Log, but seems that the error is not being logged, as you can see, all the requests in log are "OK", and I didn't find the POST envelopes/{envelope_id}/recipients.

Here are the logs files:

[image: LOGs Files]

[Content of **07_OK_GetEnvelopeRecipients.txt**:](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjnL8Rcv8DXpjh4vOatJCU-_U0fb)

Comment: Sorry you're having this trouble. The only real way for us to help you is for you to provide the call's request/response data. Get this by using the DocuSign [logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature. Then UPDATE YOUR QUESTION to include the additional info.

Comment: Hey Larry! Did the log help?

Comment: Unfortunately you weren't able to capture a log of the error. That's what you need. If the error is still happening, then: 1. Download the logs to clear the logging system. 2. Rerun your application to cause the problem. 3. Download the logs again and you should see the log of the problematic call.

Comment: See this is the strange thing, i still get the error, but the problematic call is not logged. What could cause the problematic call not being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out what is causing the problem:

Apparently, the JSON returned from the GET `envelopes/{envelope_id}/recipients` is returning the field "identityVerification" as an array. But the POST only works if "identityVerification" is an object.

[image: this is the problem]

To workaround the problem I did the following before make the POST call:

```
$recipients['signers'][$i]['identityVerification'] = new stdClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't see the error in the DocuSign logs, and also from the wording of the error, I suspect that the problem is happening within your machine, before the request is sent to DocuSign.

So the solution is to debug within your application. For more help, please provide your code which causes the error to be raised.

Comment: Thanks for the help Larry! Take a look in my answer, maybe this is a problem with the API.